# Using Facebook SDK to publish on user feed / wall

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to post on the users' wall from my Facebook application.
At the moment I have:

- One Facebook app with the permission to write on the users' wall
- A BackEnd with Fairbooks SDK Installed

Actually I'm following this approach:

```
    public static string GetToken()
    {
        var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = APP_ID,
            client_secret = APP_S,
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });
        return result.access_token;
    }

    public static void Post(string Message, long UserID)
    {
            var token = GetToken();
            var client = new FacebookClient(token);
            client.Post("/" + UserID + "/photos", new { url = "url", caption = Message });
    }
```

My final goal is to post on facebook when the user interact with my API without client-side popups. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code calls for an application access token

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = APP_ID,
            client_secret = APP_S,
            grant_type = "client_credentials"
        });
```

It makes no sense to use this if you haven't first retrieved a user access token in advance. Only then can you make calls on behalf of the user.

> My final goal is to post on facebook when the user interact with my API without client-side popups. Is this possible?

This will never be possible by design. All 3rd party applications must invoke a client-side activity for the user in some format. It cannot be automated.